# Declaration Error when defining function to return token name

Tags: solidity, erc-20, declaration

I am trying to create an ERC20 contract. Below is my code for it.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract ERC20Interface {

mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;

mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;

uint256 private _totalSupply;

string public _name;
string public _symbol;

event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}

contract SafeMath {
function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
    c = a + b;
    require(c >= a);
}

function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
    require(b <= a); c = a - b; } function safeMul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) { c = a * b; require(a == 0 || c / a == b); } function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) { require(b > 0);
    c = a / b;
   }
}



contract MyToken is ERC20Interface, SafeMath {

string public name;
string public symbol;
uint8 private decimals; 

uint256 public _totalSupply;

mapping(address => uint256) balances;
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) allowed;


constructor() {
    name = "MyToken";
    symbol = "DDDF545";
    decimals = 0;
    _totalSupply = 100000000000000000000000000;

    balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
    emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
}

//return name of token
function name() public view virtual override returns (string _name){
    return _name = name; 
   }
}
```

The lines :

```
function name() public view virtual override returns (string memory){
    return name; 
}
```

are leading to an error that says =>
DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.

Answer (score 1):

you have a public state variable named **name**

```
string public name;
```

The compiler automatically creates getter functions for all public state variables with the same name

that is the reason why the compiler is complaining with the following message:

> DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.

Comment: So can someone retrieve the name without an explicit function declared to return it?

Comment: exactly, you don't need to create the function because the compiler creates it for you

Comment: I again get an error for the same function even when string is declared private. Is there no way to implement the function name()?

Comment: in that case, you can change the name of the private variable (you could use _name) but you don't need to create the function if you use the public variable